# Advice on the best config for web hosting scenario on Azure

Tags: azure, configuration, cloud-hosting

I've been trying different scenarios/configs and finally decided to just ask for your advice...the Azure forum linked me here so I hope this is the right spot!

Just going crazy with the many different variables...need a solid, FAST, web hosting solution that I have much, if not complete, control/access.

I have a Wordpress site with 75K custom posts, a 2 gb mysql db, getting about 10,000 visits a month, currently on a shared 1and1 hosting package. Now I'm looking to implement some advanced search functionality using either "Views" or something like "Php Maker"...any of these tools, or ones like it, are resource intensive as they allow searching from the custom fields in the db.
I have credits on Azure so...

1. Linux/Lamp or Windows Wamp or Windows IIS? And I'm not a great Linux admin.
2. Can I, should I, setup the MySql on it's VM?
3. What would you all recommend for a minimum, solid, config?
4. Do I really "need" an availability set?
5. A Linux DB server and an IIS webserver?

I'm not sure where to spend the money - if I host the DB on it's VM and beef it up is that fact that it's not on the webserver VM going to cost me any of that benefit?

I've been searching for some general documentation outlining specific web hosting, website, scenarios but the data I've found is not at all conclusive - it's all over the place!

Finally (although I think I know the answer to this one ;) - can I access VM's, or Azure services, spanning multiple user accounts? A friend has offered his corporate account where he has a few hundred a month in credits - it would be cool if I could setup the DB there, at least, and the webserver on my account.

I very much appreciate your time and advice!
Rob

Comment: This question is fairly broad and opinion-based, making it not a good fit for StackOverflow. WordPress may be hosted as Web Apps (part of App Service) or a VM. MySQL may be run via ClearDB's service, or in a VM. The discussion around availability sets is something completely different, and related to High Availability. And then... accessibility is yet another completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

The last thing wou want to do is create and maintain VMs.  Create an Azure website with a WordPress template, use ClearDB for your MySQL DB (the standard MySql option for Azure websites) - you'll need to get a paid solution for this size of DB.

With Azure website extensions, like Kudu, you can use any browser to maintain your files, or use a standard FTP option.

Comment: this is one option, but certainly not definitive. And the OP is actually asking multiple questions (how to host a website; how to run the db; what about availability sets; and accessibility.  This question will end up being closed as opinion-based anyway... (or too broad)

Comment: Hey Viper - actually, it is the First thing I want - I need to start from a VM. And, while broad, it's not "multiple" questions - it's one - "What is the best Azure VM hosting config for my variables?" Everything else is just things I've thought of. There doesn't appear to be any chart showing "This type of content, this many users, this size database, required SLA", and so on, to even give a rough idea of what might be needed for doing "X". I know I don't need 56gb of ram - but other's may not. Given the choices offered it would make sense to have some sort of parametric search available.

Comment: I'm confused David - where should post? The Azure support page linked me to StackOverflow as the site to get "answers from Azure experts.." ;)

Comment: why do you need a VM?  if you are going to the cloud, a VM is very limiting.

Comment: @Rob50 - StackOverflow is an independent web property, with its own rules. Yep, post on StackOverflow. But the questions still need to follow the rules regarding on- vs off-topic. These aren't my rules... http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @viperguynaz - I'm not sure why you're so dismissive of VM's. Depending on performance and scale requirements, MySQL in a VM might be a far more performant option than hosting on ClearDB. And VMs are becoming very easy to manage, especially with container technology. Again, it's all opinion and discussion (which is why this question doesn't fit on StackOverflow).

Comment: Hi David, I didn't think they were your rules ;) I know there's quite a few Stack properties - I just mix them up sometimes. I know there's a more general site - is it Superuser? Although I still find it strange that MS provides a link to this site when you click on the Azure support page. That said I guess I'll just keep trying different combinations, doing my own benchmark testing, and see if I can't come up with an optimum solution! If I do, that may just be the basis for my next article…thanks!

Comment: And Viper - after 20 years in the Navy I wouldn't expect to agree with an AF fighter pilot all that much…;)

Comment: Ran tests, the results have been consistent - posting in case anyone else needed similar info. Stats are from the EXACT same site & db. TEST1($275.60month) An Azure Web App S2 with the Mysql DB running on an Ubuntu D2 Azure VM - Page load= 4.20s/Page Size=491kb/Requests 43. TEST2 ($267.84month)An Azure VM Windows D2 running WAMP - page load=2.67s/Size 962kb/requests=42. And TEST 1's site pages are 1/4 of the size of the TEST 2 site yet take the same time to load. Each utility gave TEST1 a much higher score. Would anyone know why this would be? FYI - my 1and1 host plan at $4.00month beat both.